# DNS record configuration for a website with the mail server hosted on different server, domain (FQDN) and IP

Tags: dns, mx, dynamic-dns

I am running into a problem which is as follows:

I have two domain names with different IPs;

The first is `EXAMPLE.COM` to host my website. Say the IP for `EXAMPLE.COM` is `111.111.11.11`.

The second domain is an FQDN to host my email, say that it is `MAIL.EXAMPLE2.io`.

The DNS Console currently supports these record types on the graphical interface: `A`, `AAAA`, `CNAME`, `MX`, `NS`, `SRV`, `TXT`.

I want to add `A` record for `MAIL.EXAMPLE2.io` on the DNS of my website `EXAMPLE.COM`. But the website DNS has `EXAMPLE.com` by default with each A record I add.

For example, if I want to add the below:

```
# Name              Type       Value
mail                IN A       1.2.3.4
```

It will become like this:

```
# Name                            Type       Value
MAIL.EXAMPLE.IO.example.com         A       222.222.22.22
```

Or, I can add `MAIL` alone, and it will become `MAIL.Example.COM`.

How can I solve this problem where I enter the A record to become:

```
# Name                Type       Value
MAIL.EXAMPLE.IO         A       222.222.22.22
```

Cloudflare has a better DNS configuration, and it will resolve my problem, but I don't want to use it on this website.

To better illustrate what I see, please look at this image:

[image: screenshot]

When I run `sudo docker-compose logs --tail=200 -f acme-mailcow`, I get these errors:

> - Cannot match your IP `222.222.22.22` against hostname `autodiscover.EXAMPLE.COM` (DNS returned `111.111.11.11`)
> - Cannot match your IP `222.222.22.22` against hostname  `autoconfig.EXAMPLE.COM` (DNS returned `111.111.11.11`)

**Update:**

The purpose of this update is to answer questions I received in the comments and make them visible to everyone.

1. **example2.io**
   The DNS configuration for **example2.io** where I host my mailserver is below. This is inline with [mailcow](https://mailcow.github.io/mailcow-dockerized-docs/prerequisite-dns/#references) documentation:
   [image]
   Note that the root directory of this website points to a different IP other than the mailserver (i.e., `333.333.33.33`)
2. **example.com**
   The DNS configuration for the domain **example.com** where I want to host a website in the root directory is below. I want the emails of **example.com** to be handled through a mailserver hosted on **mail.example2.io**.
   [image]
   To properly configure the mail on this domain, I want to remove **.example.com** from the configuration. That was possible on cloudflare DNS configuration.
3. **example3.com**
   example3.com is a domain name that I have its DNS record configured through Cloudflare and its email is handled through the mailserver **example2.io**. The DNS record configuration of this domain is below and this is how I am trying to configure **example.com**.
   [image]

Comment: Where is this hosted?  It doesn't look like a cpanel interface, what is it?

Comment: Hetzner DNS console.

Comment: How is the DNS configured for `example2.io`?  Where do the `NS` records point? Is it configured with the same DNS servers as `example.com`?

Comment: Thank you very much, @Stephen Ostermiller ♦, for editing my original question and making it read better! I highly appreciate it. The answer to your questions should be our starting point. I agree. I have updated the question and included three different DNS configurations.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you really want is to have `mail.example.com` resolve to the IP address of `mail.example2.io`. To do this, add a record of type `CNAME`, with `mail` as the name, and `mail.example2.io` as the value. `mail.example.com` would then resolve to `222.222.222.222`. This is exactly how the autoconfig and autodiscover records shown in your screenshot have been configured.

You can't add a record with `mail.example2.io` as the FQDN to the DNS zone `example.com`, as such a record could not be part of that zone. I can promise you that Cloudflare would not let you do this either.

Comment: Alternatively, have the A record for `mail.example.com` resolve to the same IP as `mail.example2.io`.

Comment: Thank you, @tim-fountain! I made changes to my original question and added three different DNS records. I also changed `mail.example2.io`  in the first image to  `mail`. Now, when I go for your suggestion and add a record of type `CNAME`, with `mail` as the name, and `mail.example2.io` as the value, I get this error message: `Another record with this name already exists.` I added Cloudflare DNS configuration for `example3.com`; this is how I want the configuration of `example.com` to be.

Comment: If you already have a mail A record pointing at the IP address of mail.example2.io, then that is equivalent to my suggestion (and is also what GeoffAtkins suggested above). What isn't working with that configuration?

Comment: You are right! When I run `sudo docker-compose logs --tail=200 -f acme-mailcow, I get these errors` I get:  `Cannot match your IP 222.222.22.22 against hostname autodiscover.EXAMPLE.COM (DNS returned 111.111.11.11)`  and `Cannot match your IP 222.222.22.22 against hostname autoconfig.EXAMPLE.COM (DNS returned 111.111.11.11)`

Comment: Also, I don't want the email to be accessible through `example.com`. What I mean by this is when anyone types `mail.example.com` etc... they get the error page. I achieved this with Cloudflare DNS configuration where the email is not accessible on `example3.com`. That is not the case with the current DNS configuration of `example.com`.

Comment: In that case, what is the purpose of the `A` record you are trying to add? Email delivery is controlled by `MX` records, which you already have in place.